# Embed PDF without toolbar and scrollbar. Why doesn't this work?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I have the following code but it does not work, I can still see the scroll bars, toolbar etc

```
 <embed width="100%" height="900" src="T:\D\CODE1000.pdf#zoom=90&pagemode=none&scrollbar=0&toolbar=0&statusbar=1&messages=0&navpanes=0"/>
```

when I use the object tag, the pdf does not show at all.

I am using IE6

Comment: Some good suggestions are on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/best-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is not aware of local paths. You should put the pdf on your webserver and modify the `src=""` path to that location.

It should be something like `src="http://www.mywebsite.com/pfds/CODE1000.pdf#blablabla"`.
More info about web paths can be found here: http://www.boogiejack.com/server_paths.html

Imagine that any website would have access to your local harddrive. Scary...

Comment: its just for testing. the pdf shows fine with the embed tag but it ignores the parameters

Comment: What do you expect the parameters to do? `SRC` indicates where to get the media object to be embedded.